# Делаю авторизацию возникла проблема помогите

Tags: php, сессия

Делаю авторизацию для администратора и вылезла такая ошибка бьюсь очень долго помогите вот эта ошибка выскакивает [изображение](http://joxi.ru/823ODvYspe8M2O) 
по адресу [ссылка](http://f22508-hostde6.fornex.org/admin/authors/) и код где выдает ошибку.

```
function userIsLoggedIn()
{
if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'login')
{
    if (!isset($_POST['email']) or $_POST['email'] == '' or
      !isset($_POST['password']) or $_POST['password'] == '')
    {
      $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Пожалуйста, заполните оба поля';
      return FALSE; 
    }

    $password = md5($_POST['password'] . 'f22508_fast');

    if (databaseContainsAuthor($_POST['email'], $password))
    {
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = TRUE;
        $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['email'];
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        session_start();
        unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
        unset($_SESSION['email']);
        unset($_SESSION['password']);
        $GLOBALS['loginError'] = 'Указан неверный адрес электронный почты или пароль.';
        return FALSE;
    }       
}

if (isset($_POST['action']) and $_POST['action'] == 'logout')
{
    session_start();
    unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
    unset($_SESSION['email']);
    unset($_SESSION['password']);
    header('Location: ' . $_POST['goto']);
    exit();
}
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn']))
{
    return databaseContainsAuthor($_SESSION['email'],
    $_SESSION['password']);
    }       
}

function databaseContainsAuthor($email, $password)
{
include 'db.inc.php';

try
{
    $sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author
        WHERE email = :email and password = :password';
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $s->bindValue(':password', $password);
    $s->execute();  
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Ошибка при поиске автора.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

$row = $s->fetch();

if($row[0] > 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
    }       
}

function userHasRole($role)
{
    include 'db.inc.php';

try
{
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM author
        INNER JOIN authorrole ON author.id = authorid
        INNER JOIN role ON roleid = role.id
        WHERE email = :email AND role.id = :roleId";
    $s = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $s->bindValue(':email', $_SESSION['email']);
    $s->bindValue(':roleId', $role);
    $s->execute();      
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
    $error = 'Ошибка при поиске ролей, назначенных автору.';
    include 'error.html.php';
    exit();
}

$row = $s->fetch();

if ($row[0] > 0)
{
    return TRUE;
}
else
{
    return FALSE;
   }        
 } 
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Он пишет, что уже отправил заголовок. Проблема не здесь, а в вызывающей функции, наверно. Вообще print должен быть ОДИН раз, потому что с первым print-ом отправляется заголовок (который потом уже не изменить)

UPDATE:или второй вариант - у Вас здесь есть session_start(). Посмотрите, не выполняется ли session_start дважды (или более)